# Unable to a Custom Collection into a text File

Tags: java, generics, serialization, queue, adt

I'm creating a generic type `ArrayQueue` and I'm trying to save an `ArrayQueue` into a text file.

*My code:*

```
public void saveToFile(ArrayQueueInterface<Payment> paymentQ){
    try {
        File file = new File("payment.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream ooStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        ooStream.writeObject(paymentQ);
        ooStream.close();
        //this.dispose();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : File not found");
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : Cannot save to file");
      }
}
```

The output showed was: "ERROR: Cannot save to file"

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Here's the full stack trace :

```
at client.TestPayment.main(TestPayment.java:844)
java.io.NotSerializableException: adt.ArrayQueue
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at entity.PaymentOperation.saveToFile(PaymentOperation.java:337)
at entity.PaymentOperation.addPayment(PaymentOperation.java:72)
at client.TestPayment.init(TestPayment.java:545)
at client.TestPayment.main(TestPayment.java:844)
java.io.NotSerializableException: adt.ArrayQueue
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
```

Comment: the exception message tells you exactly what's wrong:  java.io.NotSerializableException: adt.ArrayQueue

Answer (score 0):

In order to serialize `ArrayQueueInterface<Payment>` successfully, the implementation of your `ArrayQueueInterface` should implement `Serializable` interface (judging by the information in the stack-trace, it's not the case).

The same applies to the `Payment` class.

***Note:***

- The whole object graph should be serializable, i.e. all the fields of `Payment` (and if some of the fields are custom type, then their field as well) should implement `Serializable`.
- All primitive type are serializable, and all the standard classes from the JDK (apart from `Object` and `Optional`). So you need to care primary about your custom classes.

There's caveat regarding *desirialization*:

- All the parent classes of your custom types should be either serializable, or provide a no-args constructor (explicit or implicit), because in order to create an instance of a subclass firstly we need to create an instance of the parent type. If this requirement is violated, your object would be serialized successfully, but attemp of desirialization would fail.